# how to secure critical data Blazor serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, security, blazor, blazor-server-side

i have my connectionstring stored in my appsetting.json in my blazor serverside app
it make me no felling good when i know that my password is there in my code..

i know that in JAVA there is for exemple Glassfish who store critical data in Password Aliases, and not in the source code.
[image]

Is there something similar in .netcore? blazor serverside?
Or a solution for store critical data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Secret Manager for **local environment**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows

For **production** you have many choices: Azure KeyVault, CI/CD pipelines configuration - variables substitution (Azure DevOps, Octopus Deploy, Github Actions, etc.), Environment variables, etc

Comment: Thanks @Pawel Maga i will try, wich one can you advise me ? the simplyiest one ? Thanks :-)

Comment: @KhalidAb it depends on your hosting model. Azure Key Vault is a great cloud-based solution. If you use CI/CD servers you can use also their secret managers, e.g. free Github Actions. 
For local environment it's easy and IMHO `dotnet user-secrets` tool is the best option to use.